# Magento 2 Payment method Instruction in API

Tags: magento2, api, payment-methods, rest-api

Fetch **Instructions** for Payment method in Magento 2's existing API `/rest/V1/carts/mine/selected-payment-method`

Magento APIs doesn't provide any Instructions for Payment method, Even after selection of payment method for CART API

**Method**

```
/rest/V1/carts/mine/selected-payment-method
```

[image]